# Encountering an error while attempting to create a game

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I'm trying to create a crossword puzzle game using Actionscript 3.0 in Adobe
Animate. For the game coding, I followed an online tutorial and now I'm encountering an error. The error occurs whenever I'm in the actual game scene, no errors are encountered on the home page or instruction page. can anyone help me? my coding skills are below basic.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
> at CROSSWORD_CODE_fla::MainTimeline/entFrame().

```
stop();
quitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quitt);
function quitt(evt: MouseEvent): void {
gotoAndStop("start");
}


var hippopotamus: Number = 0;
var horse: Number = 0;
var eel: Number = 0;
var frog: Number = 0;
var ant: Number = 0;
var turtle: Number = 0;
var tiger: Number = 0;
var bird: Number = 0;
var penguin: Number = 0;
var orca: Number = 0;
var octopus: Number = 0;
var owl: Number = 0;
var snail: Number = 0;
var duck: Number = 0;
var kangaroo: Number = 0;
var iguana: Number = 0;
var ALLwords:Number = 0;
var Total:Number = 0;

{
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
function entFrame(evt:Event):void {
if ((hypoH.text == ("h").toString()) 
&& (hypo1.text == ("i").toString()) 
&& (hypoP.text == ("p").toString()) 
&& (hypoP2.text == ("p").toString()) 
&& (hypoO.text == ("o").toString()) 
&& (hypoP3.text == ("p").toString())
&& (hypoO2.text == ("o").toString()) 
&& (hypoT.text == ("t").toString()) 
&& (hypoA.text == ("a").toString()) 
&& (hypoM.text == ("m").toString()) 
&& (hypoU.text == ("u").toString()) 
&& (hypoS.text == ("s").toString())) 
{
    hippopotamus = 1;
    trace("hippopotamus");
}

} 
{
if ((hrsO.text == ("o").toString()) 
    && (hrsR.text == ("r").toString()) 
&& (hrsS.text == ("s").toString()) 
&& (hrsE.text == ("e").toString())) 
{
    horse = 1;
    trace("horse");
}
} 
{

if ((eelE.text == ("e").toString()) 
    && (eel1.text == ("l").toString())) 
{
    eel = 1;
    trace("eel");
}
} 
{
if ((penP.text == ("p").toString()) 
    && (penE.text == ("e").toString()) 
&& (penN.text == ("n").toString()) 
&& (penG.text == ("g").toString()) 
&& (penU.text == ("u").toString()) 
&& (pen1.text == ("i").toString()) 
&& (penN2.text == ("n").toString())) 
{
    penguin = 1;
    trace("penguin");
}
} 
{
if ((brdB.text == ("b").toString()) 
    && (brdR.text == ("r").toString()) 
&& (brdD.text == ("d").toString())) 
{
    bird = 1;
    trace("bird");
}
} 
{
if ((octO.text == ("o").toString()) 
    && (octC.text == ("c").toString()) 
&& (octT.text == ("t").toString()) 
&& (octO2.text == ("0").toString()) 
&& (octP.text == ("p").toString()) 
&& (octU.text == ("u").toString())) 
{
    octopus = 1;
    trace("octopus");
}
}
{

if ((orcR.text == ("r").toString()) 
    && (orcC.text == ("c").toString()) 
&& (orcA.text == ("a").toString())) 
{
    orca = 1;
    trace("orca");


    }
 }

{
if ((owlO.text == ("o").toString()) 
    && (owlW.text == ("w").toString())) 
{
    owl = 1;
    trace("owl");
}
}

{
if ((nailS.text == ("s").toString()) 
    && (nailA.text == ("a").toString()) 
&& (nail1.text == ("i").toString()) 
&& (nailL.text == ("l").toString())) 
{
    snail = 1;
    trace("snail");
}
}


 {
 if ((dkD.text == ("d").toString()) 
    && (dkU.text == ("u").toString()) 
 && (dkC.text == ("c").toString()) 
 && (dkK.text == ("k").toString())) 
 {
    duck = 1;
    trace("duck");
 }
}

{
if ((groA.text == ("a").toString()) 
    && (groN.text == ("n").toString()) 
&& (groG.text == ("g").toString()) 
&& (groA2.text == ("a").toString()) 
&& (groR.text == ("r").toString()) 
&& (groO.text == ("o").toString())) 
{
    kangaroo = 1;
    trace("kangaroo");
}
}

{
if ((frgF.text == ("f").toString()) 
    && (frgR.text == ("r").toString()) 
&& (frgG.text == ("g").toString())) 
{
    frog = 1;
    trace("frog");
}
}

{
if ((ignG.text == ("g").toString()) 
    && (ignU.text == ("u").toString()) 
&& (ignA.text == ("a").toString()) 
&& (ignN.text == ("n").toString())) 
{
    iguana = 1;
    trace("iguana");
}
}

{
  if ((antA.text == ("a").toString()) 
    && (antN.text == ("n").toString())) 
{
    ant = 1;
    trace("ant");
}
} 
{
if ((trtT.text == ("t").toString()) 
    && (trtU.text == ("u").toString()) 
&& (trtR.text == ("r").toString()) 
&& (trtT2.text == ("t").toString()) 
&& (trtL.text == ("l").toString())) 
{
    turtle = 1;
    trace("turtle");
}

}


{
if ((tgr1.text == ("i").toString()) 
    && (tgrG.text == ("g").toString()) 
&& (tgrE.text == ("e").toString())) 
{
    tiger = 1;
    trace("tiger");
}
}

ALLwords = hippopotamus + horse + eel + frog + tiger + octopus + penguin + bird + orca + 
turtle + duck + snail + ant + kangaroo + iguana + owl;
Total = 16 - ALLwords;
if (Total == 0) 
{
trace("Gameover");
    }
    
incorrectTXT.text = ("you have" + Total+ " incorrect words remaining").toString();          
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that one of the variables in your `entFrame()` function is null. Check that you have correctly defined all of the TextFields you reference there (I'm assuming on your stage)? `hypoH` etc

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. Error #1009 means that you are trying to access the field or method of some instance, that is not there at the moment (think of it as of trying to shake hands with the person that is not actually here). In order to narrow your problem to a certain line, go to **File** > **Publish Settings** menu and turn the **Permit Debugging** option on. You will still get the error, but now you will know the exact line of code that is the problem and learn which one of these multiple **TextField**s cannot be addressed (due to misspelled instance name or something).